# How can I make a YouTube video in an iframe go full screen?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

When i embed YouTube video in iframe it works fine but in full mode the video is not visible entire the screen

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/rGmF2CaDiBg?rel=0" 
        frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" class="iframe" 
        id="Overlayvideo" **allowfullscreen="true"**>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your css
`#Overlayvideo {   width: 100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

**HTML** :

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/rGmF2CaDiBg?rel=0" 
        frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" class="iframe" 
        id="Overlayvideo" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

**CSS** :

```css
iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```